# Attempt when checking if file has permission for read, write, and execute

Tags: bash

I have tried to check if the given input of the file name has permission to read, write, and execute

-XML

```
echo -n "Enter file name: "
read file
# checks if file has write permission or not
[ -w "${file}" ] && W= "Write = yes" || W= "Write = No"

# checks if file has execute permission or not
[ -x "${file}" ] && X = "Execute = yes" || X= "Execute = No"

# checks if the file has read permission
[ -r "${file}" ] && R= "Read = yes" || R= "Read = No"

echo "$file permissions"
echo "$W"
echo "$R"
echo "$X"
```

However, when I input a file's name, I get these errors:

```
Write = yes: command not found
Write = No: command not found
Execute = No: command not found
Read = yes: command not found
Read = No: command not found
```

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` is picky when it comes to spaces around `=` in assignments. Remove them all. Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter file name: "
read -r file
# checks if file has write permission or not
[ -w "${file}" ] && W="Write = yes" || W="Write = No"

# checks if file has execute permission or not
[ -x "${file}" ] && X="Execute = yes" || X="Execute = No"

# checks if the file has read permission
[ -r "${file}" ] && R="Read = yes" || R="Read = No"

echo "$file permissions"
echo "$W"
echo "$R"
echo "$X"
```